# Mapping.json in Ui-kitten can not working?

Tags: react-native-ui-kitten

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CQxx.png)How can try this using their code in react native @ui-kitten. I try for 2 days it's using mapping.json. In applicationProvider attribute custommapping={mapping}. but it not succeeded. How can I implement in react-native file

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjbc2.png)

Comment: i am trying @ui-kitten component in react-native in TEXT INSIDE LAYOUT . How can i colorful text using ui-kitten

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear. I don't know much about react but, to use it in angular, we have to import the map library from rxjs/operators.
I think this will be helpful: [React map object and embedded object from JSON and convert to single array for state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53121326/react-map-object-and-embedded-object-from-json-and-convert-to-single-array-for-s)